# Filter() formula ignoring blank cells

Tags: drop-down-menu, filter, excel-formula, formula, cells

I'm trying to use the filter() formula within a spreadsheet, from another tab within that spreadsheet.

I've got a number of drop-down menus that, when used, bring up the relevant data from the table I'm filtering from.

I've managed to make it work when it's a table of data from row 2 downwards (row 1 being a header row), but now the table starts from the 6th row down with other information above it (most of it, however, is blank). As such, now all of the options come up automatically when the drop down menus are blank.

I either need the formula below to start from the 6th row down, or to ignore the blank cells. It must be an easy solution but for the life of me, I can't find it anywhere on the internet (I'm pretty new with spreadsheet formulas so please be gentle).

This is the formula I've been using that works when there are no blank rows:

=FILTER(Sheet2!A:T,(Sheet2!D:D=B12)+(Sheet2!F:F=C12)+(Sheet2!G:G=D12)+(Sheet2!H:H=E12)+(Sheet2!I:I=F12)+(Sheet2!N:N=G12)+(Sheet2!O:O=H12)+(Sheet2!T:T=I12))

If it helps, the drop-down options are both numbers and text, and I'm using Google Sheets rather than Excel.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably just change your ranges to 'A6:T' instead of 'A:T'.  'A:A' range syntax gets all rows in that column.  'A6:A' will start it at 6 but not define an ending row, which I think is what you want.

This is your formula with those small changes:

=FILTER(Sheet2!A6:T,(Sheet2!D6:D=B12)+(Sheet2!F6:F=C12)+(Sheet2!G6:G=D12)+(Sheet2!H6:H=E12)+(Sheet2!I6:I=F12)+(Sheet2!N6:N=G12)+(Sheet2!O6:O=H12)+(Sheet2!T6:T=I12))

The =isBlank() formula may be useful to you as well.  It takes a cell reference and returns true/false.  You can wrap this in NOT() to give the opposite result, i.e =NOT(ISBLANK(A1)) will return true if there is a value.

Comment: Thanks zbnrg - I think I tried this and when it didn't work I second-guessed myself. It looks correct but it just isn't working for some reason. Is it because the table it's pulling the filter data from has itself been imported from another spreadsheet? I think Google Sheets is getting too confused and won't return the correct results.